# How to Bind Data to Grid View in a Row Formate in UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

In order to support my application to all devices I am migrating my application from **WPF** to **UWP**. 
Here I am facing one GUI Issue.  **i.e,**

Please check the attached screen shot of my WPF application.
Now I want to develop the same GUI using UWP.
But not getting exact GUI.Its coming in a different formate.
Please Help me to get the same Kind of GUI using **UWP**.

Here in UWP application I am Using **Grid View**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think GridView is the control you should be looking for. GridViews are used to make a grid of "items". Your table is more of a list (I guess based on the data) where each row is an item right?

In that case it's probably better to use a listview

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465465.aspx

Within the listview you can create a datatemplate containing the "columns".

How was the WPF UI built up, using what controls? I'll assume it was a DataGrid. Those are not available in Windows 8 or 10 because they are more focused on touch interaction. There are some 3rd party libraries available which you could use. Here is a link comparing some of the 3rd party solutions:
http://liftcodeplay.com/2015/10/24/datagrid-alternatives-in-uwp/

Comment: Thank you @GeetvdC for your Reply... You may be right ... but I have tried both Grid view and List view both are giving the same kind of out puts ... Cant we show the result like as I have mentioned above GUI Using UWP?

Comment: @sagar what did you use in WPF to generate the UI, was it a DataGrid? DataGrid's haven't been around sine Windows 8 because they are not working that well for touch applications. More info on this: http://liftcodeplay.com/2015/10/24/datagrid-alternatives-in-uwp/

Comment: Yes I have used DataGrid in WPF.

Comment: is the link in above comment helpful on how to work with displaying grids of data?

Comment: Yes it helped me... Now I am able to Develop the Required GUI... need to check the events ... Thank you